# How to get seen/unseen status of IMAP message

Tags: go, imap

I've read over the go [documentation](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap) as well as the general imap [documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) but can't seem to find the correct way to get the status of a particular message - to know if it is marked as read or unread.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
// 
//Code that set up 'c' and 'cmd' ...
//
for cmd.InProgress() {
    // Wait for the next response (no timeout)
    c.Recv(-1)

    // Process command data
    for _, rsp = range cmd.Data {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        header := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.HEADER"])  // Contains subject, from data
        uid := imap.AsNumber(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["UID"])  // Message unique id
        body := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.TEXT"])  // Message body
        //seenState := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["Flags"])
        if msg, err := mail.ReadMessage(bytes.NewReader(header)); msg != nil {
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            //START CUSTOM
            if strings.Contains(msg.Header.Get("Subject"), genUUID()){
                fmt.Println(rsp.Label)
                fmt.Println(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["Flags"])
                fmt.Println(c.Status("INBOX", string(uid)))
            }
            //END CUSTOM
```

For output I get:

```
FETCH
<nil>
LAOYU10 STATUS "INBOX" (Þ) <nil>
```

The documentation that I've cited has led me to believe that at least one of my methods should be printing if the message is marked as unseen. What am I missing?

EDIT:
I am testing against an inbox (gmail) with four messages. The first two are read and second two are unread. Here is the output for all four messages.

```
FETCH
<nil>
SIHLB7 STATUS "INBOX" (Û) <nil>
FETCH
<nil>
SIHLB8 STATUS "INBOX" (Ü) <nil>
FETCH
<nil>
SIHLB9 STATUS "INBOX" (Ý) <nil>
FETCH
<nil>
SIHLB10 STATUS "INBOX" (Þ) <nil>
```

Comment: Side note, your `uid` variable is of type `uint32`, it makes no sense to do `string(uid)` unless you expect that number to be the value of a single valid Unicode code point (see [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type)). You probably want [`strconv.FormatUint`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint) or `fmt.Sprintf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Couple things to note, make sure you're actually requesting the flags field in your imap request. If you're issuing a fetch, then you'll have to pass in `"FLAGS"` as an argument to `Fetch`, additionally, the flags attribute in `Attrs` is case sensitive, so you'll need `rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["FLAGS"]`. Below is a working example of using imap in Gmail with the go-imap library, run it with `GMAIL_EMAIL=email.address GMAIL_PASSWD=mypassword go run go_file.go`

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    label := "INBOX"
    email := os.Getenv("GMAIL_EMAIL")
    passwd := os.Getenv("GMAIL_PASSWD")

    conf := &tls.Config{
        Rand: rand.Reader,
    }

    c, err := imap.DialTLS("imap.gmail.com:993", conf)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect")
    }

    defer c.Logout(30 * time.Second)

    c.Data = nil

    if c.Caps["STARTTLS"] {
        c.StartTLS(nil)
    }

    // Authenticate
    if c.State() == imap.Login {
        c.Login(email, passwd)
    }

    if c.State() != imap.Auth {
        panic("Authentication error")
    }

    c.Select(label, true)

    set, _ := imap.NewSeqSet("*")

    cmd, err := c.Fetch(set, "FLAGS", "UID")
    if err != nil {
        panic("Bad fetch command")
    }
    _, err = cmd.Result(imap.OK)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Bad fetch response")
    }
    for _, rsp := range cmd.Data {
        seen := false
        for _, flag := range imap.AsList(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["FLAGS"]) {
            if flag == "\\Seen" {
                seen = true
            }
        }

        if seen {
            fmt.Printf("Message %d has been read!\n", imap.AsNumber(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["UID"]))
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Message %d has been not been read!\n", imap.AsNumber(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["UID"]))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch with the case sensitivity. Thanks very much! So do you think this is a typo in the documentation then? I got 'Flags' from this section specifically http://code.google.com/p/go-imap/source/browse/go1/imap/response.go#256

Comment: @Morgoroth: Actually, I hadn't read the MessageInfo structure documentation very carefully, if you notice, `Flags` is actually an attribute of the MessageInfo struct, not a key in Attrs. The library seems to internally set the Flags attribute by grabbing `Attrs["FLAGS"]`, check out https://code.google.com/p/go-imap/source/browse/go1/imap/response.go#274. So basically you can either do the `imap.AsList(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["FLAGS"])` call or just do a range over `rsp.MessageInfo().Flags`. Either works, but `rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["Flags"]` will not.

Answer (score 1):

```
fmt.Println(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["Flags"])
```

That prints `<nil>` for you because no flags are set, which means the message is "unseen".

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear in my question about what i've tested against. I've edited the question to include this information.

Comment: Actually, no flags being set should return an empty array according to go-imap documentation, the flags attribute is case sensitive, and should be `"FLAGS"`, not `"Flags"`

Comment: The flags attribute is case INsensitive, cf. RFC3501 page 81.

Comment: @arnt - I don't care if the RFC says that the response is case insensitive, the library that @Morgoroth is using normalizes all responses by uppercasing--so, as I posted, and as directly read from the source of the library, the proper key for the `Attrs` map is `"FLAGS"`, not `"flags"` or `"Flags"` or any other combination

Answer (score 1):

Each message has a list of flags in IMAP, one of which is called \seen (case insensitive, as are most things in IMAP). If the flags list does not contain that flag, the message is unseen.

The answer from @jstedfast explains how to get the flags list. The rest is a matter of splitting at whitespace and checking whether any word in the list equals \seen.